# How to filter out numbers with Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with Spark Structured Streaming and trying to filter out negative numbers from fields streamed from a lab. My code looks like this:

```scala
val records = labs.filter(
$" data.trays.tray1” <= 5 ||
$" data.trays.tray2" <= 10 ||
$" data.trays.tray3" <= 20)
.select("data.labs", "data.labs.tray1", “data.labs.tray2”, “data.labs.tray3”)
.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```

My output with the code above is:

```
Lab  |  Tray 1 | Tray 2 | Tray 3
----------------------------------
FGF       0       -8       13   
RFF      -3        9      -14   
WER       2       -8      -16
```

However, I am missing the the logic to filter out the negative numbers.  I thought I had if figured out, but I can't seem to filter them out

Comment: If you want to filter negatives why do you care about 5, 10, 20? Just do `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will keep all values such that the predicate returns `true`. Try

```
val records = labs.filter(
$"data.trays.tray1" > 5 &&
$"data.trays.tray2" > 10 &&
$"data.trays.tray3" > 20)
.select("data.labs", "data.labs.tray1", "data.labs.tray2", "data.labs.tray3")
.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
```